# Sys.InvalidOperationException when trying to edit page in sharepoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, web-part, updatepanel

I added a webpart through VS2010. It is a Simple webpart containing ajax script manager,timer and update panel. what it does is it shows the current server time in a label. 
After i deploy it into my sharepoint site i get following error when clicking on edit page.

> "Sys.Invalid Operation exception: Could not find updatePanel with ID 'ctl00_m_....pnlTimer'. If it is being updated dynamically then it must be inside another Update Panel."

This error goes when i remove the updatepanel in my code.How can i get rid of this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My error got resolved automatically after a system restart. Without any changes being made in the code or anywhere else.

Answer (score 2):

You may be surprise why you are getting this message though your UpdatePanel is very much on the page. Generally this error comes when you are trying to update an UpdatePanel from code behind and that UpdatePanel is inside an element (parent) that has hidden visibility.

Some techies suggest you to use another UpdatePanel as a container of your this UpdatePanel. Keeping in mind that UpdatePanels are the region like PlaceHolders and not like asp.net Panel element.

Please read complete post here: [InvalidOperationException could not Find UpdatePanel with ID](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/Blogs/10808/invalidoperationexception-could-not-find-updatepanel-with-id.aspx)

Comment: Thank you for this answer.I will keep this in mind but it didnt help me.

Comment: My error got solved automatically after a system restart. Without any changes being made in the code.